# Перевод из 10 в 16 систему счисления

Tags: ассемблер

Задача, написать макрокоманду для выборки из некоторого массива десятичных чисел повышенной точности в распакованном формате всех элементов с заданным значением паритета. С помощью этой макрокоманды обработать два массива, в первом из которых имеется 100 20-ти разрядных чисел, а во втором - 50 30-разрядных чисел. При этом из первого массива выбрать числа с четным паритетом, а из второго с нечетным паритетом.

Данные выглядят примерно так:

```
Var DB 2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6; 2233445566 десятичное 10-ти значное число
```

Для вычисления паритета нужно перевести в 16 систему счисления (другого способа я не знаю). Как перевести это число?
Используется MASM под процессор аналогичный Intel8086 (16 разрядный)

Comment: А что такое паритет в Вашем случае?

Comment: И что такое "макрокоманда"? Если макрос (что сомнительно), то нужно уточнить какой именно ассемблер используется, везде макросы разные.

Comment: @KoVadim вот именно, неизвестно что такое паритет для 10 чисел, а вот для 16 известно, но если я буду вам объяснять я где то что скажу не правильно и это вас запутает =) Главная сложность перевести в 16 вид, а дальше уже легко

Comment: Меня запутает? Может все таки дадите ссылку?

Comment: @PinkTux я дописал в вопросе про ассемблер и процессор. Макрос используется: abc macros x,y,n,paritet ..... abc endm. Как то так

Comment: @KoVadim какую ссылку дать?

Comment: Ссылку на описание паритета чисел

Comment: А вам точно нужен макрос для перевода в двоичное представление? Теоретически и его написать можно, но функцию было бы куда проще и логичней использовать.

Comment: у меня нету её к сожалению, я в книге нашел её, тоесть суть заключается в том, что нужно посчитать количество единиц в байте вроде, если их количество нечетное, то паритет нечетный, а если четное - то соотвественно паритет четный. Паритет определяется флагом PF если не изменяет память

Comment: То есть вам нужно тупо определить чётность результата?

Comment: @PinkTux да, макрос нужно, если вы знаете как перевести, можете просто написать, а в макрос я уже сам добавлю, это не сложно)

Comment: @PinkTux Четность не самого числа, тоесть у числа 8 я так понимаю нечетный паритет, так как его код в 2 системе выглядит так 1000.
Единица здесь одна, поэтому и паритет нечетный

Comment: Добавил в ответ подсчёт суммы битов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перевод ваших чисел в двоичное представление. Собирал nasm + gcc, но, думаю, под другой ассемблер (и разрядность) переделать не проблема. Но учтите, что указанное число в 16 разрядов никак не влезет. Или вам тоже нужно использовать 32-битные операции, или хранить результат в паре регистров:

```
; ------------------------------------------
section .data
decnum  db  2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6
declen  equ $ - decnum
fmt     db  '%u', 0Ah, 0

; ------------------------------------------
section .text
extern printf
global main
main:
    ; тут храним результат
    xor edi, edi
    ; выборка разрядов - с конца
    mov esi, decnum + declen - 1
    mov ecx, declen
    ; текущий показатель степени
    mov ebx, 1

convert_loop:
    movzx eax, BYTE [esi]
    ; если бы число задавалось не двоичными цифрами, а 
    ; символами (decnum db '2233445566'), то здесь
    ; надо добавить:
    ; sub al, '0'
    mul ebx
    add edi, eax

    ; следующий разряд увеличиваем в 10 раз
    mov eax, 10
    mul ebx
    xchg eax, ebx
    dec esi
    loop convert_loop

    ; двоичное представление в edi, проверяем:
    push edi
    push fmt
    call printf
    ; ура, вывело строку "2233445566"

    ; а стек после printf восстанавливать 
    ; не обязательно, всё равно выходим    
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 80h
; ----------------------------------------
```

Сумма битов числа:

```
    ; число в ebx
    mov ebx, 8
    ; количество разрядов:
    mov ecx, 32
    ; результат:
    xor eax, eax

parity_loop:
    shr ebx, 1
    adc eax, 0
    loop parity_loop
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую под себя собрать отпишусь минут через 15, спасибо!

Comment: По первому взгляду, мне надо будет для edi(в моем случае, для di) сделать косвенную адресацию на участок памяти, туда и записывать результат. После каждой итерации смещать [di + 1]. Что бы не произошло переполнения нужно флаг переноса запоминать и использовать команду ADC. Здесь походу больше чем на 15 минут(( Отпишусь скоро

Comment: Просто у вас все в регистр влезает, а у меня по заданию 20 и 30 значные числа

Comment: @helldrg Для 20-30 значных в десятичной системе вам нужен обратный double dabble алгоритм. в принципе гуглится, правда с трудом

Comment: @PinkTux Спасибо большое! Единственное не получается с увеличением разрядности правильно выполнять операцию сложения в цикле. Если не получится у меня сделать, я еще одну тему создам, надеюсь поможете =)

Comment: @Mike это сложный алгоритм(

Comment: @helldrg тогда деление в столбик. Вы приведенный тут алгоритм не адаптируете для большого количества разрядов. Вот вы в новом своем вопросе пытаетесь что то там складывать внутри цикла из этого ответа, но это в корне не верно. Пока цикл не прошел весь входной массив результат не известен, промежуточные данные не говорят ни о чем

Comment: @Mike Про деление столбиком звучит не плохо, могли бы примерно накидать как это выглядет. Я в asm не силен(